# Нужно оптимизировать код на kotlin

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, kotlin, оптимизация, скорость

Есть задача:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ce399e0047a45001c853c2b/train/kotlin

Код, который я написал для её решения:

```
fun sumParts(ls: IntArray): IntArray {
        // your code
        var res = IntArray(size = ls.size + 1)

        for(i in ls.indices){
            var sum: Int = 0
            for (j in i until ls.size){
                sum += ls[j]
            }
            
            res[i] = sum
        }

        return res
    }
```

При проверки выскакивает следующая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Грубо говоря, код работает, но при работе с большими данными, скорость его работы недостаточно велика. Я уже оптимизировал всё, что мог. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что ещё можно с этим сделать?

Comment: Вам не нужен вложенный цикл. Заполняйте res с конца. Каждый раз вам надо добавлять к сумме очередной элемент массива ls.

Comment: Попробуйте переписать вопрос. Сейчас в нем ни условия, ни проблемы толком не обозначено ..

Comment: @КириллМалышев, оформите Ваш комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его принять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужен вложенный цикл. Заполняйте res с конца. Каждый раз вам надо добавлять к сумме очередной элемент массива ls.

Что-то вроде такого:

```
var sum: Int = 0
for(i in ls.size - 1 downTo 0){
    res[i + 1] = sum
    sum += ls[i]
}
res[0] = sum
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Посчитайте общую сумму
2. Ещё раз пройдите по списку, отнимая очередной элемент от суммы и выводя результат